# Get records where date.year == some_year in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a date column in my database in a Rails 3.1 app, and I want to be able to get the records where the date's year matches a specific year.
I tried `where(:date.year == year)` but of course I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'year' for :date:Symbol`. Is it possible to do this type of query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a scope to build something like:

```
scope :for_year, lambda {|date| where("date >= ? and date <= ?", "#{date.year}0101", "#{date.year}1231")}
```

Comment: This worked: `scope :for_year, lambda {|year| where("date >= ? and date <= ?", "#{year}-01-01", "#{year}-12-31")}`

Comment: These answers are great, but I didn't know what a scope was. So basically you have to define the scope in the model.rb file. Then the scope acts like a normal method that can be called, except that it's specialized in dealing with active record (database) calls. And in the example above, you could call something like user.for_year(1991), and the 1991 represents the |year|.

Answer (score 3):

In your Model:

```
scope :by_year, lambda { |year| where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', year) }
```

In your Controller:

```
@courses = Course.by_year(params[:year])
```

Answer (score 1):

Jesse gave you, I think, the idea for the actual solution, but to explain why this failed - it's because it tried to evaluate ".year" as a method on the symbol you passed it: ":date".

The word :date is just a parameter to tell "where" which value it will later use to construct the SQL query to pass to the db.
It doesn't turn into the actual date of the record. But the ".year" will evaluate as you're passing it as a parameter, before anything has been done with the ":date" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date format is: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Try this:

```
where(Date.strptime(:date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").year == year)
```

OR

```
where(["YEAR(?) = ?", :date, year])
```

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: can't dup Symbol`

Comment: How are you getting your `year`?

Comment: year is a method argument, and is an integer like 2011, 2010, etc.

Comment: The second example gives me: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: YEAR`

Comment: Ye s- sqlite doesn't have date functions (eg YEAR) but mysql does. You could switch to using mysql - especially if you're going to be deploying to it.